# Not able to understand the correlated queries

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

Could someone help me in understanding the correlated queries. Here is the below query which I am trying to understand but not able to get anything out of it. Kindly help. Thank you.

```
--Step 1
    select e1.Name as 'Employee', e1.Salary
    from Employee e1
    where 3 >
    (
        select count(distinct e2.Salary)
        from Employee e2
        where e2.Salary > e1.Salary
    )
    ;




--Step 2 
SELECT
    d.Name AS 'Department', e1.Name AS 'Employee', e1.Salary
FROM
    Employee e1
        JOIN
    Department d ON e1.DepartmentId = d.Id
WHERE
    3 > (SELECT
            COUNT(DISTINCT e2.Salary)
        FROM
            Employee e2
        WHERE
            e2.Salary > e1.Salary
                AND e1.DepartmentId = e2.DepartmentId
        )
;
```

Comment: In First step they want to get less then 3 distinct employee of e1 those  have less salary compare to e2 employee And in 2nd They want to get same as 1st but where department is same

Comment: Well, considering the first query, you have a problem, because the first query doesn't really do what (I think) it's trying to do - which (I think) is to return the employees with the three highest salaries.

Comment: I don't understand it either.  Assuming you have to change somebody else's work, you might be better off starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

In the first query you are returning all e1.Name and e1.Salary where the employee has 2 or fewer records where their salary is greater than in e1.

The second query does the same thing, but only when the employee has not changed departments.

Answer (score 0):

A legitimate query to find employees with the top 3 salaries might be as follows:

```
 SELECT x.* 
   FROM employee x 
 HAVING FIND_IN_SET(salary,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT salary ORDER BY salary DESC) FROM employee)) <= 3;
```

Note: This may return more than 3 employees, if employees share the same salary

Answer (score 0):

Lets break them down:

Step 1 - Return all employees having a salary in top 2 salaries (3>x).

- (SELECT) Return the name of all employees and their salary
- (FROM) the employee table
- (WHERE) Exclude employees who do not have a salary in the top 2. the subquery simply counts the number of salaries greater than the current evaluated record.  If that number is more than 2, then this person doesn't have a salary in the top 3. 3 > 4 = as would 3 > 3 false and the record is excluded.

.

```
SELECT e1.Name as 'Employee', e1.Salary
FROM Employee e1
WHERE 3 > (SELECT count(distinct e2.Salary)
           FROM Employee e2
           WHERE e2.Salary > e1.Salary);
```

Another way to write this query would be to

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee E1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM Employee E2
              WHERE E1.Salary = E2.Salary
              ORDER By salary Desc 
              LIMIT 2)
```

The above basically says return the top 2 salaries and the employees who have one of those salaries.

Step 2 is similar to step 1; but because the correlation is on department as well, the results are different.  For each employee it identifies if the salary is one of the top 2 for the department.  If it is the record is included.  This means the top 2 salaries are evaluated by department instead of company wide like step 1.

Step 2 could also be re-written however,

In languages besides mySQL this could be represented by:

1. using a window/analytical function Dense_rank() and partition by department; and then limit to records to those having a rank 2 or less
2. using a cross apply and a top 2 ordered by salary desc.
3. in mySQL the method listed is the easiest approach w/o using user variables. to simulate the window function or cross apply above.